# consumer in kafka without loss message

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

Using microservices application layer using Spring, when a service publishes a message into kafka topic, 
the other service that consumes that message is down.
When it comes back, will it reprocess from where it had stopped?
Is there something to be set up in order to not lose any messages?
The main idea is to process that message as streaming.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122517/2575224

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Kafka please be careful about offset management. Offset is the number which is kept for each TopicPartition - ConsumerGroup combination. You should take a look at the following parameters in Kafka:

```
offsets.retention.minutes
log.retention.hours
```

If you are using high level java api;

```
auto.offset.reset
```

There are so many cases that the offsets might get lost. So, i recommend you to implement idempotent consumers to have a chance to re-consume messages when things go wrong. In this way, you may get some messages multiple times but your consumer doesn't process them. It simply skips them to get next messages.

Answer (score 0):

> will it reprocess from where it had stopped?

It should, if your consumer has not committed the consumed offsets.

If your application restarts between an auto-commit interval then you will experience duplicate messages, though, starting at the most recent committed offset for the consumer group.

You're able to manually control the commit, if this is not wanted behavior